# Swap values when they're being referenced by foreign key

Tags: mysql

If for example I have one table with a column `table_1.column_a`, and another table with a column `table_2.column_b`. The values in `table_2.column_b` are referencing the `table_1.column_a` as foreign keys.

Once there is a situation where two entries in `table_1.column_a` have to be swapped, be it for testing purposes or real-world reasons (for example swapping which team two players belong to), what is the easiest way to achieve that, without breaking the foreign key constraints?

Currently every time I have to do that, I drop the foreign key constraint(s), in order to swap the data, and then define they foreign keys constraints again.

Is there some kind of swapping mechanism, whether it's some built-in functionality or just some hacky query that I can use, that would allow me to swap two entries without having to drop and then recreate the foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

This is a small hack.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

swap your records

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: please check this and let me know

Comment: Also a great way to screw up your system.

Comment: yes that's why i  say it's hack and not a recommended method. if you want to do such thing that indicate your having some design issue in your DB

Comment: Note, a hack can mean one thing to one person, another to another. To me a hack means it works, awesome. But you expose the system to data problems the second it goes to 0. And there is no mention of that. There simply is no reason to do this safely as a programmer of an app. This is best for offline data imports like mysqldump and imports.